# Infinite sum of reciprocals of pentagonal numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, closed-form

How do I find this sum: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p(n)}$$ where

$p(n)=\dfrac{n(3n-1)}{2}$ is the $n$th pentagonal number?

I know it is a convergent series, but I don't know if the sum can be found in closed form.

Comment: Do you have some specific reason for thinking it can be found in closed form rather than only numerically? (It's clear that it converges, so some numerical work should be able to give us a number as accurate as we need for any occasion.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: i don't think so if i can be found it in closed form .however it's clear that it is convergent serie

Comment: Unhelpful comment: There is a closed form that I don't remember.

Comment: $S=\log 27-\frac{\pi\sqrt3}{3}$

Comment: Googling "sum of reciprocals of pentagonal numbers" finds http://www.personal.psu.edu/jxs23/downey_ong_sellers_cmj_preprint.pdf and various other possibly useful references.

Comment: @VladimirLenin, your sum it's computed numerically

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another way to do is just use basic calculus without using the digamma function: Let
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n(3n-1)}x^{3n}. $$
Clearly $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n(3n-1)}=f(1)$. Note
$$ f'(x)=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3n-1}x^{3n-1},f''(x)=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{3n-2}=\frac{6x}{1-x^3}. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
f(1)&=&\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{6t}{1-t^3}dtdx\\
&=&\int_0^1\int_t^1\frac{6t}{1-t^3}dxdt\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{6t(1-t)}{1-t^3}dt\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{6t}{1+t+t^2}dt\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{6t}{(t+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})^2}dt\\
&=&3\ln3-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 10):

Using 
$$
   \frac{1}{p(n)} = 2 \left( \frac{1}{n-\tfrac{1}{3}} - \frac{1}{n} \right)
$$
and the definition of the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p(n)} = -2 \left( \psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) + \gamma \right) = 3 \ln(3) - \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \approx 1.48204
$$

The value for the $\psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$ can be derived from $\psi\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, states in the [table of special values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values) using the reflection identity.